# Magento Change order status to complete without invoicing

Tags: magento, status

I have a Ecommerce Store with Downloadable product. When customer order something. then customer can't download product until my creation of invoice for it. So i need a solution then when customer will order and order will be complete and customer can download product automatically without my invoice creating. please give me a solution

thanks

Answer (score 3):

We've done this because Magento's invoicing feature is a useless step for any company using QuickBooks or similar to create invoices. The long and short of it is that you can change the order *state* and *status* (read up on these) using the Order model's `setState()` and `setStatus()` methods. Setting an order status to `complete` is as simple as this:

```
$orderOBJ = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order->getId());
$orderOBJ->setStatus('complete');
$orderOBJ->save();
```

We've even extended Magento to include a quote generator, creating a whole new type (state) of order which is treated as an internal quote until a customer approves the quote, at which time it is converted to an order.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, Can you please give the file path where can i change it, thanks

Comment: @Jason how to change order status to complete from admin?

Answer (score -1):

I've used a different approach by adding the option Complete to list of available status. I've written an article about it at [my blog](http://blog.mdnsolutions.com/index.php/magento-free-order-with-status-as-complete/). I hope it helps.

Comment: I get "400 Bad Request"